# Why does it suffice to define the homogeneous projection operator by only testing with continuous instead of measurable functions?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, projection, borel-measures, wasserstein

In [Lenaic Chizat's "Sparse Optimization on Measures with Overparametrized Gradient Descent"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01636-z) one finds the following definition: for a measure $\mu \in \mathcal P_2(\Omega)$ (the [Wasserstein-2-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition) on $\Omega := \Theta \times \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, where $\Theta$ is a compact Riemannian manifold) we define homogeneous projection operator $\mathsf{h} \colon \mathcal P_2(\Omega) \to M_+(\Theta)$ (where $M_+(\Theta)$ are the nonnegative Radon measures on $\Theta$), where $\mathsf h \mu$ is characterized by
$$
\int_{\Theta} \psi(\theta) \, \text{d}(\mathsf h \mu)(\theta)
= \int_{\Omega} r^2 \psi(\theta) \, \text{d}\mu(r, \theta)
\qquad \forall \psi \in \mathcal C(\Theta; \mathbb R).
$$

**My question.**
Why is $\mathsf h \mu$ defined umambigously via integration against all continuous functions and why don't we have test will are Borel measurable functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows for example from the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), that asserts that any linear positive form on the space of compactly supported continuous functions defined on a locally compact set is associated to a unique Radon measure on that set.

Comment: In my case, $\Theta$ is compact, so the  compact supported condition is vacuous, right? Further, the linear positive form in my case is $$\Phi_{\mu} \colon \mathcal C(\Theta; \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R, \qquad \psi \mapsto \int_{\Omega} r^2 \psi(\theta) \, \text{d}\mu(r, \theta),$$ right? Because then the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem tells us that there is a unique nonnegative measure $\mathsf h \mu$ such that $\int_{\Theta} \psi(\theta) \, \text{d}(\mathsf h \mu)(\theta) = \Phi(\psi)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.